# Get method with parameter

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

i am trying to get `barcode` variable while `qty` variable is 0 or !=.Like Select barcode Where qty=0 or Select barcode WHERE qty=0. I spend whole my day but i didnt figure out how to make this. Please help me

```
@GetMapping(path = "/barcode/{barcode}")
    public List<User> findd(@PathVariable("barcode") String barcode,
                            @RequestParam Integer qty) {
        return repository.findByQty(qty);
    }
```

s

```
public interface UserRepository extends JpaRepository<User,Integer> {

    User findByBarcode(String barcode);
    List <User> findByQty(int qty);




}
```

[image: hc]

Answer (score 0):

You are just fetching the results by quantity here which is absolutely wrong.
There are multiple products having quantity as 0.
So you must pass quantity and barcode both to fetch results.
For example:
Select barcode from table_name where barcode=666 and qty=0.

At the controller method level, you can easily pass path variable the same way as you are passing qty.